# Approximation to the energy produced by the Sun per cubic centimeter

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry

Good afternoon, I'm trying to do an approximation to the Energy produced by the Sun per $cm^3$

So I am assuming a bunch of things, first of all, the density of the Sun's core is $\rho=150 \frac{gr}{cm^3}$ and it's composed by only by Hidrogen.

So, 1 mol of hydrogen weigh 1 gram and has $6.022x10^{23}$ molecules, then in $1cm^3$ we have $6.022x10^{23}\cdot150$ molecules $\rightarrow$ $9.033x10^{25}$ molecules.

And I know that each H-H reaction (that involves 4 Hidrogen molecules each) produces 17.3 MeV so, given that I want to calculate the total energy pero cubic centimeter, the question is, how many molecules actually fuse in a given moment????

As an approximation i could say that all, or even half of them, but i wanted to know if there is a better approximation...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

At the level you're working, you can find the total luminosity using the [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant). Then, using the fact that the sun is fusing at near equilibrium, you assume that the energy generation is spread out through the volume of the core. The rest is left as an exercise.